# How can I play a Youtube video in an iPhone

Tags: ios, ios4, uiwebview, media-player

I wanted to play a Youtube video in the iPhone from within the application. I tried using the MPMoviePlayerController, but was not loading the video. It is playing the video which I loaded from the bundle but not the you tube video. I also tried to play the Youtube video by embedding it in the UIWebView, but that also was in vain. Can anybody suggest me an approach that i should take. i am testing it in the IOS 4.2

This is the code i used.

```
mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

  if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
  {
    // Set movie player layout
    [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                       selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                       name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                       object:nil];
    }  
  else
  {
    // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                         name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                         object:nil];
  }

  // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                        selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                        object:nil];
```

Answer (score 8):

The only way to play youtube videos on iOS is to play them using default youtube player. You should embed the video in a uiwebview and when you tap/click on it the default player will open refer this code to embed video in uiwebview-

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {
 NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
 <style type=\"text/css\">\
 body {\
 background-color: transparent;\
 color: white;\
 }\
 </style>\
 </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
 width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
 NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
 if(videoView == nil) {
    videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
 }
 [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this method. It was working for when i tried it on versions before 4.0. Now i tried this approach on Simulator 4.2 but is not working. Was it working for you on any SDK above 4.0,

Comment: this approach will not work on simulator.. it will only work on iphone device